# Azure Multiple Deployments 409 Conflict

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-deployment

We have a deployment process through the CircleCI to the Azure Web Service zip deploy. We have multiple deployments per day to the development instance(it's being automatically deployed once PR is merged to the `development` branch). But we sometimes into following error: CircleCI run jobs in parallel, which also includes deploy script. If Azure receives multiple deploy requests at the same time(or until one is not finished) it goes down and after all, always responds with the 409(Conflict) error.

Is there any way to fix this?

P.S. I'm currently thinking about this solution https://circleci.com/orbs/registry/orb/eddiewebb/queue#usage-examples for the CircleCi to not run multiple parallel deployments. But what about Azure? Can I somehow restart/reboot it?

Comment: Definitely 409? Or 429? If 429: Could be a throttling issue with the Azure Resource Manager API (1,200 write requests / hour and 12,000 read requests per hour, per resource manager instance).

Comment: Yes, it's 409 Conflict